# Subscribing to a event from a WPF control in C++

Tags: c++, wpf-controls

I've a simple WPF clock user control called AnimClock, and in the code behind, i've declared an event like this:

```
public EventHandler OnTick;
```

I've a C++/CLI dll which references this WPF control. However, the compiler (VS2010) isn't recognising the fact that AnimClock has an event called OnTick :

```
Globals::gwcClock = gcnew WPFControls::AnimClock();
... 
Globals::gwcClock->onTick+=gcnew EventHandler(OnWPFAppEvent);
```

The above line yields an ''onTick' : is not a member of 'WPFControls::AnimClock' error.

However, I am able to call methods on AnimClock through my gwcClock reference - so how do i declare events in my WPF control such that they can be subscribed from C++ ?

Comment: Is is really `OnTick` and `onTick`?

Comment: AHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH !! ok - it was a typo. It's fine now